# Apache Flink Rules over Async Data Streams

Tags: asynchronous, apache-flink, datasource

I have been struggling with flink features to be able to solve below detailed problem;

1. There are more than one data source fed asynchronously. Means;
   One message source sends messages in every X seconds and other message source sends messages in every Y seconds.
2. I would like to apply some rules based on the latest values of these sources' specific values;
   for example;

val(x) > 10 and val(y) > 20

3. What I  have done so far is; 
   Filtering these two different sources and getting the only values I do care about and keeping them in a hash map and feeding another stream with this hash map.

[image: hash map stream last element life cycle]

4. This process event runs the rule over per hash map instance and then take appropriate action.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two streams, you can connect them and feed them into a [CoFlatMapFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/co/CoFlatMapFunction.html), which can then keep track of the latest value from each stream, and emit results based on the application of your rules to these values.